# Error al enviar una petición Post por Guzzle en laravel 7

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Me marca este error al enviar un archivo a una api,
Envió el archivo por POST por medio de la librería guzzle, este es el codigo donde envio el archivo

```
$client = new Client([
        
        'base_uri' => 'http://192.168.2.10:8000/api/archivos',
        
        'timeout'  => 10.0,
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://192.168.2.10:8000/api/archivos', [
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name' => '123.pdf',
                'contents' => fopen('archivos/123.pdf', 'r')
            ],
        ]
    ]);
```

Estoy enviando el archivo fijo pero la intención es enviarlo mediante un request con INSOMNIA.
Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que se pueda enviar el archivo, lo debó recibir en la otra api, pero no se como responder a la petición que realizo, es decir enviar el archivo y después guardarlo en la otra api y por ultimo retornarlo.
Graciass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `base_uri` es aquello común que tienen tus rutas, usualmente es el dominio. Por [ejemplo](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html), si quieres acceder a estas rutas:

```
https://foo.com/api/clients
https://foo.com/api/workers
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       base_uri
```

Como ves, la base es lo que está subrayado ya que es algo común entre esas dos rutas. Por ende crearías el cliente así:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.com/api/']);
```

Posteriormente, dado que ya tienes la base, sólo te queda añadir la ruta relativa, que será a donde quieres ir:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'clientes'); // https://foo.com/api/clients
$response = $client->request('GET', 'workers');  // https://foo.com/api/workers
```

En tu caso, tu base_uri es una ruta completa y luego, al hacer la petición, vuelves a poner la misma ruta.

Dada la explicación anterior, tu Guzzle debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://192.168.2.10:8000/api/']);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'archivos', [...]);
```